# how can I do online Expectation–maximization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

em algorithm is usually optimized iteratively between the expectation and the maximize the likelihood with the whole data. I want to use the em algorithm with a single sample or a mini-batch. And how to optimize in the expectation step and re-estimate parameters in the maximization step? 
[See here]https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373958/how-can-i-do-online-expectation-maximization-algorithm

Comment: Are you talking about using a single sample, or perhaps a min-batch, in the expectation step, rather than using all the data to compute the expectation?

Comment: Yes. I really mean that I want to use the em algorithm with a single sample or a mini-batch. And how to optimize in the expectation step and re-estimate parameters in the maximization step?

Comment: You have now clarified what the question is. I suggest you edit your question to reflect this, and perhaps someone (not me) will answer it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. I've edit it again.

Comment: Maybe you should post this at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and provide a link in the new post back to this one, and from this post to the new post.  I'd like to see a knowledgeable person answer this or at least provide good comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had post this problem at the stats.stackexchange.